# ElasticSearch search issues

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I setup ElasticSearch and I'm able to upload my file. It contains a list of json objects.

```
     {
        "Indicator": "Alabama",
        "Level": 468671,
        "Units": "Billion Btu",
        "As Of": 2011,
        "YTD": "-4.95%",
        "-5": 469036,
        "-10": 460201
    },
    {
        "Indicator": "Alaska",
        "Level": 33524,
        "Units": "Billion Btu",
        "As Of": 2011,
        "YTD": "-0.10%",
        "-5": 20654,
        "-10": 17878
    },
    {
        "Indicator": "Arizona",
        "Level": 174841,
        "Units": "Billion Btu",
        "As Of": 2011,
        "YTD": "4.12%",
        "-5": 173934,
        "-10": 280064
    }
```

I used the command

```
    curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/coal/production/1' -d @coal.json
```

and it inserted the index. However, when I go to query it, I get everything back.

This is the query I'm running.

```
    curl -XGET 'http:localhost:9200/coal/production/_search' -d '{
"query": {
            "match": {
                "Indicator": "Alabama"
            }
        }
}'
```

I'd like to only get back the first item. Have I setup my index incorrectly? I feel like I've missed something here.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you have indexed the 3 documents as only one  : using a PUT /{index}/{type}/{id} is how you do a single insert.

Try to make a `match_all` query like this :

```
curl -XGET 'http:localhost:9200/coal/production/_search'
```

And you will see you have only one document that contains everything.

You have two possible solutions, choose between :

- Separate the three items and index them one by one (PUT /coal/production/1 then 2 and 3)
- Use the **bulk API** but beware : it has a special format to use, just check the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk)

Comment: I uploaded it using coal/production/1 coal/production/2 coal/production/3 and was able to get back the right result. I thought that the last number was more for versioning but I went back and read again that its just an ID. There is also a version associated with that ID. Thanks so much clearing things up for me!